# How to show my devices in my custom google map

Tags: gps, gps-tracking, external-gps

I have 5 mobile devices with me, all these devices have GPS. On my map i need to view all the devices wherever it is located. And GPS will be turned on. Please help me

Comment: not like that..I have a separate fragment in my application, with map.

Answer (score 0):

Android Device Manager is perfect for this.

Just download and set up the app on all of these devices (if the app isn't already on them), and you're pretty much ready to go.

As long as all of these devices are signed into the same Google Account, and the GPS is on on all of these devices, you won't find it very hard to locate them.

click [here](https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager), and you will see just what I am talking about. You can also use the app to lock your device, ring it on full volume, and even wipe the phone completely.  It is basically Google's "Find My iPhone"